# javascript basic slider wont work

Tags: javascript

Got this basic slider, but I cant make it work. Checked code quite few times now, cant see my mistake..
Can someone please show me where i'm wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mySlides = new Array('first.gif','second.gif','third.gif','fourth.gif');
        var slide = 0;
        function showSlide(slideNumber){
            slide = slide + slideNumber;
            if(slide>mySlides.length - 1){
                slide=0;
            }
            if(slde<0){
                slide=mySlides.length - 1;
            }
            document.displaySlide.src=mySlides[slide];
        }
</script>

<body>
<p><img src="first.gif" name="displaySlide"></p>
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="showSlide(-1);" />
<input type="button" value="Forward" onclick="showSlide(1);" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mySlides = new Array('first.gif','second.gif','third.gif','fourth.gif');
        var slide = 0;
        function showSlide(slideNumber){

            slide = parseInt(slide)+parseInt(slideNumber);
            if(slide == -1)
            {
                slide = 0;
            }
            alert(slide);
            if(slide > mySlides.length)
            {
                slide = mySlides.length;
            }

            document.displaySlide.src=mySlides[slide];
        }
</script>
```